# Swift: Why is my completionHandler closure returning a value?

Tags: xcode, swift

I am trying to create an HTTP request and return some JSON data. It is connecting to the API correctly and returning data but when I run the app it is returning the line I printed ("Error") without continuing through the application. If I remove the println and continue through the breakpoints the app just runs forever with me being unable to continue through the breakpoints.

I'm sure I have some fundamental misunderstanding of how closures are supposed to work. What am I missing here?

```
func logIn() {

    var url = "https://www.photoshelter.com/psapi/v3/mem/authenticate?api_key=(api_key)&email=(email)&password=(password)&mode=token"
    var baseURL:NSURL? = NSURL(string: url)
    var request: NSMutableURLRequest? = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: baseURL!)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    println("Error")
    var responseObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil)

    })
    task.resume()
}
@IBAction func signInButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    logIn()
}
```

Comment: IDK why you want to print something there if the code works.

Comment: I think you should read an article about closures/threads/asynchronous requests.

Comment: Sorry I didn't saw the closures.

Comment: The way you're doing it is totally fine. It *always* would print "Error" (that's why o don't understand why you print "Error" - the comet ion block (or closure) gets always called. It depends on its arguments whether it the request finished (if you have a `data` object that is not nil or an error).

Comment: If you want to do something after you received that `data` object (or an error) you need to pass a completion block into your `login` function like `loginWithCompletion(completion: (success: Bool, data: JSON) -> Void)` (I'm on mobile so the exact signature might differ a little bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This or a close variation is how I do nearly all of my networking. It looks like your implementation isn't actually doing anything.

```
func logIn() {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.photoshelter.com/psapi/v3/mem/authenticate?api_key=(api_key)&email=(email)&password=(password)&mode=token")
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    // Request
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    // You can set request properties like HTTPMethod and HTTPBody to customize things

    let loginUserDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        var success = false

        if let error = error {
            println("Failure! \(error)")
            if error.code == -999 { return }
        } else if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                if let array = parseJSON(data) {
                    success = true
                    // Do something with array
                }
            } else {
                println("Failure! \(response)")
            }
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        }
    })
    loginUserDataTask?.resume()
}
```

and here is `parseJSON:` to handle the data:

```
func parseJSON(data: NSData) -> [AnyObject]? {
    var error: NSError?
    if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &error) as? [AnyObject] {
        return json
    } else if let error = error {
        println("JSON Error: \(error)")
    } else {
        println("Unknown JSON Error")
    }
    return nil
}
```